# Do we need the Rx System.Reactive.* assemblies?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have been trying to program with `Rx` these days.

Now every time I start of the programming with it, I get on to the question, that do I really need the external SDK libraries like `System.Reactive.*` assemblies. As whenever, I want to program using `Rx`, I have to use observable : `IObservable`, `IObserver` etc., but these are already available in the `mscorlib` assembly.

So why should I download these reactive assemblies and add there references ?

Comment: The `BCL` defines the `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>` interfaces, but the System.Reactive libraries include classes which implement them, along with linq extensions and methods of converting to/from tasks and events.

Comment: Thanks Lee for answering. So now can I program with Rx without using these libraries ? Or at some place I would really require these ?

Comment: The Rx library defines all the linq combinators like `Select`, `Where`, `SelectMany` etc. which are a powerful way of dealing with event streams. If you're dealing with observers and observables, I would definitely recommend you use Rx, otherwise you'll have to define your own implementations of the interfaces, and working with them will be cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

As Lee said, the base class libraries only include the core interfaces `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>`. There is nothing else there of Rx in the BCL.

To do anything useful with them, you should really leverage the reactive-extensions library (typically by including nuget package [`rx-main`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/)).

While there is nothing stopping you from making your own implementations, there are such an awful lot of subtleties in a good implementation that I think you'd be crazy to do it when Reactive Extensions has done such a fine job.

Comment: Thanks James and Lee for answering. Still can anyone please give me examples of such extension methods that are used regressly and are only available through the system.reactive assemblies. Sorry, I am really a beginner for Rx.

Comment: Have a look at this hands on lab, it's written for an older version of Rx, but should work with little or no changes: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D669F9-01DF-4FAF-BBA9-29C096C462DB/Rx%20HOL%20.NET.pdf or take a look at http://www.introtorx.com, or look at this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DEV413